# Are there any problems with branching a branch in TFS?

Tags: version-control, tfs, branching-and-merging

We branch our whole master branch in TFS, following a somewhat git-like paradigm rather than branching specific sub-folders.

I have one such branch, for a feature. However this feature ended up really being two features, one dependent on the other. It's not possible to merge back to master yet, but I would like to keep the features separate so I can merge part A while I still work on part B.

Say I am working in branch A; is it fine to branch A to branch B, and then continue working on B? I would then merge A back to master in the near future, and then merge B into master later on.

I don't know if TFS has intelligence that could make this a problem if I want to merge master -> B later on, or if TFS is totally 'dumb' with tracking branches and doesn't care about such things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TFS 2012 merging has improved considerably. Among the [improvements](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/08/31/merge-enhancements-in-tfs-11.aspx) are the auto-merge engine, which reduces the number of conflicts and the baseless merge promotion to the UI.
In your case, when there's no merge relationship between two branches, a baseless merge should be performed. Once a branch relationship is established, subsequent merges will be normal.

For more details see the [**ALM Rangers Version Control Guide**](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/).

Comment: That doesn't really address my question. I specifically said I am using branches per feature. This feature A has developed an extension B which should not delay the original version being merged to master, but needs to be worked on before A is reviewed and accepted. In Git/Hg you could branch _anything_ but I specifically want to check if TFS will have a problem merging B into master when it is not a branch _of_ master.

Comment: I've revised my answer to include baseless merging, which I think is the solution for your concerns.

Comment: Cool - we only just moved to 2012 after recently starting with 2010 so I'll have to check that out. I also saw an option called "re-parent branch" but I didn't get to check out if it's related to this.